# TLS Alert 70 (Protocol Version) Issue on STM32H563 with NetXDuo

Tags: embedded, stm32, threadx

I am using STM32H563 along with ThreadX and NetxDuo. When trying to connect to a server ([jsonplaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com)) over https I am receiving an tls alert code 70 from it

I have enabled sntp and verified that proper time is set. I am using dns to get the ip of the server (have verified that it is proper) and Tls1.3 is enabled. I am using a user defined function for a GET request from the server

My https 'GET' function is as follows :

```
UINT https_get(CHAR *resource,CHAR *receive_data, UINT wait_option)
{
    UINT ret;
    UINT get_status;
    ArduinoJson::JsonDocument doc;
    NX_PACKET      *receive_packet;
    UCHAR           receive_buffer[1000];
    ULONG           bytes;

    https_client.nx_web_http_client_connect_port = https_port;

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,(const uint8_t *)"Connecting to Server\n", strlen("Connecting to Server\n"), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

    /* Connect to the server. */
    // The connection fails here
    ret = nx_web_http_client_secure_connect(&https_client,&https_server_address,https_port,tls_setup_callback, wait_option);
    /* Check status.  */
    if (ret != NX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,(const uint8_t *)"Connection Successful\n", strlen("Connection Successful\n"), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    /* Initialize HTTP request. */
    ret = _nxe_web_http_client_request_initialize_extended(&https_client,
                                                                 NX_WEB_HTTP_METHOD_GET,
                                                                 resource,
                                                                 strlen((const char *)resource),
                                                                 (CHAR *)https_host,
                                                                 strlen((const char *)https_host),
                                                                 0,
                                                                 NX_FALSE,   /* If true, input_size is ignored. */
                                                                 https_username,
                                                                 0,
                                                                 https_password,
                                                                 0,
                                                                 wait_option);
    /* Check status.  */
    if (ret != NX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,(const uint8_t *)"Sending request\n", strlen("Sending request\n"), HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    /* Send the HTTP request we just built. */
    ret = _nxe_web_http_client_request_send(&https_client, wait_option);

    /* Check status.  */
    if (ret != NX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /* Enter the GET state.  */
    https_client.nx_web_http_client_state =  NX_WEB_HTTP_CLIENT_STATE_GET;

    get_status = NX_SUCCESS;
    while(get_status != NX_WEB_HTTP_GET_DONE)
    {
        get_status = nx_web_http_client_response_body_get(&https_client, &receive_packet, NX_WAIT_FOREVER);

        /* Check for error.  */
        if (get_status != NX_SUCCESS && get_status != NX_WEB_HTTP_GET_DONE)
        {
            Error_Handler();
        }
        else
        {
            ret = nx_packet_data_extract_offset(receive_packet, 0, receive_buffer, 1000, &bytes);
            if(ret)
            {
                Error_Handler();
            }
            receive_buffer[bytes] = 0;

            HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart3,(const uint8_t *)receive_buffer,strlen((const char *)receive_buffer), HAL_MAX_DELAY);

            nx_packet_release(receive_packet);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

my tls setup is as follows :

```
UINT tls_setup_callback(NX_WEB_HTTP_CLIENT *client_pt,
                       NX_SECURE_TLS_SESSION *TLS_session_ptr)
{
    UINT ret = NX_SUCCESS;
    NX_PARAMETER_NOT_USED(client_pt);

    /* Initialize TLS module */
    _nx_secure_tls_initialize();

    /* Create a TLS session */
    ret = _nx_secure_tls_session_create(TLS_session_ptr, &nx_crypto_tls_ciphers_ecc,
                                    crypto_metadata_client, sizeof(crypto_metadata_client));
    if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    ret = _nx_secure_tls_ecc_initialize(TLS_session_ptr,
            nx_crypto_ecc_supported_groups,
            nx_crypto_ecc_supported_groups_size,
            nx_crypto_ecc_curves);
    if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /* Allocate space for packet reassembly. */
    ret = _nx_secure_tls_session_packet_buffer_set(TLS_session_ptr, https_tls_packet_buffer,
                                               sizeof(https_tls_packet_buffer));
    if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

//  ret = nx_secure_tls_session_protocol_version_override(TLS_session_ptr,NX_SECURE_TLS_VERSION_TLS_1_3);
//  if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
//  {
//      Error_Handler();
//  }

    /* initialize Certificate to verify incoming server certificates. */

    ret = _nx_secure_x509_certificate_initialize(&trusted_certificate, (UCHAR*)ISRG_Root_X2_der,
                                                (USHORT)ISRG_Root_X2_der_len, NX_NULL, 0, NULL, 0,
                                             NX_SECURE_X509_KEY_TYPE_NONE);
    if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    /* Add a CA Certificate to our trusted store */

    ret = _nx_secure_tls_trusted_certificate_add(TLS_session_ptr, &trusted_certificate);
    if (ret != TX_SUCCESS)
    {
        Error_Handler();
    }

    nx_secure_x509_dns_name_initialize(dns_name,(UCHAR *)https_server_name,strlen(((const char*)https_server_name)));
    nx_secure_tls_session_sni_extension_set(TLS_session_ptr, dns_name);
    _nx_secure_tls_remote_certificate_allocate(TLS_session_ptr, &remote_certificate, remote_cert_buffer, sizeof(remote_cert_buffer));
    _nx_secure_tls_remote_certificate_allocate(TLS_session_ptr, &remote_issuer, remote_issuer_buffer, sizeof(remote_issuer_buffer));

    return ret;
}
```

I verified that supported cipher suites and signature algorithm are getting selected and is communicating over tls1.3.(Note: I was able to successfully communicate with the server over http)

I am not able to debug the problem as to why this is occurring.
Is there any particular extension that needs to be added or am I missing something else?
How should I go ahead with this?
Thank you

**Edit:**

I am not able to directly monitor the communication between the client (device) and server, rather I verified that the device is using tls1.3 by sending the https request to my pc which is hosting a basic tcp server using [Hercules](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) and monitor the Client Hello Msg using wireshark to verify the cipher suites and versions supported. The packet which I received from my device was :

[Client Hello Msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iCrM.png)

As for the server, I used [postman](https://www.postman.com/) for verification of cipher suites and protocol version.

[Postman Console Tls logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Esh.png)

Comment: How did you verify that you communicate using TLS 1.3? How do you know that supported cipher suites and signature algorithm of BOTH sides (client=device and server)? Do you have connected device to monitored network? If yes, show first TLS handshake packets.

Comment: @Misaz I have the verification details to my question, hope it helps to understand the problem I am facing. Thank you